# Javascript - removing last added div?

Tags: javascript, html, web

So, I'm learning Javascript and ran into an issue. I have a function that will add some boxes, when I click "Add Data", I can click this multiple times, but I want to be able to have a button called "Remove Data" that would allow me to remove the last one I added.

Code can be found here.

http://codepen.io/whyhellobradley/pen/ggKLXa

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2d96912e6f.js"></script>
<style>
    .hidden{display:none;}
    .self-input {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .green {
        color: #5b7762;
    }
    textarea, input{ font-family:monospace; }
</style>

<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Chart type: </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chartType" checked id="piechart" value="piechart" onclick="findChartType()">Pie chart
        </label>


    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add data" onClick="addInput()">Add data <i class="fa fa-plus-circle green" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="inputArea"></div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate chart shortcode" onClick="generateString(), datastring()">Generate chart shortcode</button>
    </div>

</form>
<hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" value="" id="finalString"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var chartType = document.getElementsByName("chartType");
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    var source = document.getElementById("source");
    var y_title = document.getElementById("y_title");
    var y_max = document.getElementById("y_max");
    var y_min = document.getElementById("y_min");
    var x_labels = document.getElementById("x_labels");
    var dataURL = document.getElementsByName("datalabel");
    var dataCAPTION = document.getElementsByName("dataCAPTION");


    function createInput(type, name, className=null){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = type;
        input.name = name;
        input.class = className;
        return input
    }

    function createLabel(name, text, className=null){
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.for = name;
        label.class = className;
        label.innerHTML = text
        return label;
    }

    function addInput() {
        div = document.createElement("div")
        div.appendChild(createLabel("datalabel", "URL   :&nbsp;", "control-label"))
        div.appendChild(createInput("text","datalabel","dataLabel"))
        div.appendChild(createLabel("dataCAPTION", "&emsp;Caption:&nbsp;", "control-label"))
        div.appendChild(createInput("text","dataCAPTION","dataCAPTION"))
        div.classList.add("self-input")
        document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(div);
    }


    function findChartType() {
        if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.add("hidden");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.remove("hidden");
        }
    }

    function datastring() {
        var ds = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dataURL.length; i++){
            ds +=  '<li><a class="ns-img" alt="photo_' + i + '" href="' + dataURL[i].value + '"></a><div class="caption">' + dataCAPTION[i].value + '</div></li> ';
        }
        return ds;
    }


    function generateString() {

        if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' + '<script src="script.js"  type="text/javascript"></sc' + 'ript><div id="thingy"><div class="slider-inner"><ul>' + datastring() + '</ul></div></div>';
        }

        else if (chartType[2].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = "<!--[linechart title=\"" + title.value + "\" source=\"" + source.value + "\" y_title=\"" + y_title.value + "\" y_max=" + y_max.value + " y_min=" + y_min.value + " x_labels=\"" + x_labels.value + "\" " + datastring() + "]-->";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = "Please select a chart type and complete the information for the chart.";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Any help would be really great. **Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the button by adding these two functions in your javascript

```
function createButton(type, name, className, value){
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = type;
    input.name = name;
    input.class = className;
    input.value = value;
    input.addEventListener("click", removeData);
    return input
}



function removeData() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

Then add this line to your `function addInput()`---

```
div.appendChild(createButton("button","removeData","btn-disable",   
"RemoveData"))
```

Here goes the working example--

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
<style>
    .hidden{display:none;}
    .self-input {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .green input{ font-family:monospace; }
</style>

<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Chart type: </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chartType" checked id="piechart" value="piechart" onclick="findChartType()">Pie chart
        </label>


    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add data" onClick="addInput()">Add data <i class="fa fa-plus-circle green" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="inputArea"></div>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate chart shortcode" onClick="generateString(), datastring()">Generate chart shortcode</button>
    </div>

</form>
<hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" value="" id="finalString"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var chartType = document.getElementsByName("chartType");
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    var source = document.getElementById("source");
    var y_title = document.getElementById("y_title");
    var y_max = document.getElementById("y_max");
    var y_min = document.getElementById("y_min");
    var x_labels = document.getElementById("x_labels");
    var dataURL = document.getElementsByName("datalabel");
    var dataCAPTION = document.getElementsByName("dataCAPTION");


    function createInput(type, name, className=null){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = type;
        input.name = name;
        input.class = className;
        return input
    }
    function createButton(type, name, className, value, onclick){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = type;
        input.name = name;
        input.class = className;
        input.value = value;
        input.addEventListener("click", removeData);
        return input
    }

    function createLabel(name, text, className=null){
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.for = name;
        label.class = className;
        label.innerHTML = text

        return label;
    }

    function addInput() {
        div = document.createElement("div")
        div.appendChild(createLabel("datalabel", "URL   :&nbsp;", "control-label"))
        div.appendChild(createInput("text","datalabel","dataLabel"))
        div.appendChild(createLabel("dataCAPTION", "&emsp;Caption:&nbsp;", "control-label"))
        div.appendChild(createInput("text","dataCAPTION","dataCAPTION"))
        div.appendChild(createButton("button","removeData","btn-disable", "RemoveData"))

        
        div.classList.add("self-input")
        document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(div);
    }
    function removeData() {
      this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    }

    function findChartType() {
        if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.add("hidden");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.remove("hidden");
        }
    }

    function datastring() {
        var ds = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dataURL.length; i++){
            ds +=  '<li><a class="ns-img" alt="photo_' + i + '" href="' + dataURL[i].value + '"></a><div class="caption">' + dataCAPTION[i].value + '</div></li> ';
        }
        return ds;
    }

    
    function generateString() {

        if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' + '<script src="script.js"  type="text/javascript"></sc' + 'ript><div id="thingy"><div class="slider-inner"><ul>' + datastring() + '</ul></div></div>';
        }

        else if (chartType[2].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = "<!--[linechart title=\"" + title.value + "\" source=\"" + source.value + "\" y_title=\"" + y_title.value + "\" y_max=" + y_max.value + " y_min=" + y_min.value + " x_labels=\"" + x_labels.value + "\" " + datastring() + "]-->";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("finalString").value = "Please select a chart type and complete the information for the chart.";
        }
    };
</script>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to remove the last added input. It will also check to make sure that it isn't trying to remove something that doesn't exist (checks that there are user inputs in the list).

```js
chartType = document.getElementsByName("chartType");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var source = document.getElementById("source");
var y_title = document.getElementById("y_title");
var y_max = document.getElementById("y_max");
var y_min = document.getElementById("y_min");
var x_labels = document.getElementById("x_labels");
var dataURL = document.getElementsByName("datalabel");
var dataCAPTION = document.getElementsByName("dataCAPTION");


function createInput(type, name, className = null) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = type;
  input.name = name;
  input.class = className;
  return input
}

function createLabel(name, text, className = null) {
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.for = name;
  label.class = className;
  label.innerHTML = text
  return label;
}

function addInput() {
  div = document.createElement("div")
  div.appendChild(createLabel("datalabel", "URL   :&nbsp;", "control-label"))
  div.appendChild(createInput("text", "datalabel", "dataLabel"))
  div.appendChild(createLabel("dataCAPTION", "&emsp;Caption:&nbsp;", "control-label"))
  div.appendChild(createInput("text", "dataCAPTION", "dataCAPTION"))
  div.classList.add("self-input")
  document.getElementById("inputArea").appendChild(div);
}

function removeInput() {
  inputArea = document.getElementById("inputArea");
  if(inputArea.childNodes.length > 0){
    inputArea.removeChild(inputArea.childNodes[inputArea.childNodes.length-1]);
  }
}


function findChartType() {
  if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pieHidden").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}

function datastring() {
  var ds = "";
  for (i = 0; i < dataURL.length; i++) {
    ds += '<li><a class="ns-img" alt="photo_' + i + '" href="' + dataURL[i].value + '"></a><div class="caption">' + dataCAPTION[i].value + '</div></li> ';
  }
  return ds;
}


function generateString() {

  if (chartType[0].checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("finalString").value = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' + '<script src="script.js"  type="text/javascript"></sc' + 'ript><div id="thingy"><div class="slider-inner"><ul>' + datastring() + '</ul></div></div>';
  } else if (chartType[2].checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("finalString").value = "<!--[linechart title=\"" + title.value + "\" source=\"" + source.value + "\" y_title=\"" + y_title.value + "\" y_max=" + y_max.value + " y_min=" + y_min.value + " x_labels=\"" + x_labels.value + "\" " + datastring() + "]-->";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalString").value = "Please select a chart type and complete the information for the chart.";
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2d96912e6f.js"></script>
<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .self-input {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .green {
    color: #5b7762;
  }
  textarea,
  input {
    font-family: monospace;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="chartType">Chart type:</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="chartType" checked id="piechart" value="piechart" onclick="findChartType()">Pie chart
      </label>


    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add data" onClick="addInput()">Add data <i class="fa fa-plus-circle green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Remove data" onClick="removeInput()">Remove data <i class="fa fa-minus-circle green" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="inputArea"></div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate chart shortcode" onClick="generateString(), datastring()">Generate chart shortcode</button>
    </div>

  </form>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" value="" id="finalString"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That looks fantastic!

Comment: @BradleyDeanJones if this answered your question then please be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do that.

My suggestion is:

- http://codepen.io/rmagalhaess/pen/rjKjao

Source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="Fields">
    <div id="DIV_0"> Field_0: <input type="text"> </div>
</div>
<button onClick="AddField()"> Add Field </button>
<button onClick="DelField()"> Del Field </button>
<hr>
<div id="Last_Index"> 0 </div>

<script>
    function AddField()
    {
        var Last_Index = document.getElementById('Last_Index');

        var Add_Index = Number(Last_Index.innerHTML) + 1;

            Last_Index.innerHTML = Add_Index;       

        var New_Div           = document.createElement('div');
            New_Div.id        = 'DIV_'+Add_Index;       
            New_Div.innerHTML = 'Field_'+Add_Index+': ';

        var New_Input = document.createElement('input');

            New_Div.appendChild(New_Input);     

        var Fields = document.getElementById('Fields');     
            Fields.appendChild(New_Div);
    }

    function DelField()
    {
        var Last_Index = document.getElementById('Last_Index');         

        var Del_Index = Number(Last_Index.innerHTML);

        if ( Del_Index > 0 )
        {
                Last_Index.innerHTML = Del_Index - 1;

            var Last_Div = document.getElementById('DIV_'+Del_Index);
                Last_Div.innerHTML = '';

            var Fields = document.getElementById('Fields');
                Fields.removeChild(Last_Div);
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```